# Youtube iframe API calls to playVideo/pauseVideo don't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

Sample code:

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>
<a id="start" href="#">start</a>
<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'U6oKcAXiVlo',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0, 'showinfo': 0 },
    });
  }

  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function () {
  player.playVideo();
  });
</script>
```

Reproducible test-case:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/3fpusLm5/show/

The player variable is in scope. But calls to the methods that should be available on the object (e.g. playVideo, pauseVideo) do not work. It says `Object does not support this property or method`.

The code works in most modern browsers. I am certain the player is loaded already. I have tested the onReady callback, and also tried waiting 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, IE has already given you the answer. I tested the link on IE9 in IE8 mode and received the error

**Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'**

And truly IE8 supports only **attachEvent**.

You can either check if this option exists and set the correct listener, or add an external script that will apply this option for you, like in *addEventListener Polyfill*.

Comment: Apologies. When creating the fiddle, I had some problems creating my local test-case for the fiddle. Locally I'd used jQuery, so I wrote a quick event listener and forgot that IE8 doesn't support it. You can assume that $("#start").click(function () { player.playVideo(); }); behaves in way documented in my question. I'll update the fiddle first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Well, my answer is still pretty close. You get this error because youtube is calling one or more javascript options that IE8 doesn't support. So, either look for an older embed code (I think youtube still support it for the time being) or stick with the second solution I suggested  - adding an external script that will allow older browsers accept and run more advanced script.

Comment: Well, after some juggling around I got the code to work in IE8, but it was not related to your solution. Nevertheless marked as accepted.